# Trying to get a for loop to break when it hits a certain row in html table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webtable from the wesbite found below in my code.  Basically, I am trying to only scrape today's games, and have my for loop stop when it hits the portion of the HTML table that contains the information for the next day's games.  I have tried googling this, but still can't seem to solve it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My code is posted below.

```
url='http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_id('user-header-timezone-expander').click() #get to est timezone
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'GMT - 4')]").click() #get to est timezone
time.sleep(2)

content=driver.page_source

soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')


file_dates = []
todays_games=soup.find('table',{'class':'table-main'})
dummy_row=soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'table-dummyrow'})

for games in todays_games.select('td.table-time.datet'): #gets the time of the game
    games= [games.text]
    file_dates.append(games)

    if dummy_row==dummy_row[1]: #I want the for loop to break when it hits the gray header titled "Tomorrow, 22 Jul" on the webpage
        break

print(file_dates)  #still returns every game on the website though
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get match times for Today only you can try below code:

```
games = [td.text for td in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="tournamentTable"]//td[contains(@class, "datet") '
                                                     'and following::span[starts-with(., "Tomorrow,")]]')]
print(games)
```

If you still want to use bs4, try:

```
file_dates = []
todays_games=soup.find('table',{'class':'table-main'})

for games in todays_games.select('tr')[2:]:
    if games.select('td.datet'):
        file_dates.append(games.select('td.datet')[0].text)
    if games.select('th'):
        break
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, would you be able to walk me through this xpath you provided a little bit more?

Comment: XPath returns you all cells with class name `"datet"` from `"tournamentTable"` that appears in DOM before the span that starts with the sub-string  `"Tomorrow"`

Comment: Hi, sorry to bug again, but would you have a solution for this outside of using Xpath? Your answer works great, but I was kind of hoping there was a solution where I could break out of the loop when it hits the gray date row like I tried doing in my code.  I really am curious to see what this would look like, I just can't seem to solve it this way!

Comment: I cannot even try cause page currently [is not available](https://imgur.com/a/flSCOMe)

Comment: Ok no worries! It’s back now but there is no rush at all

Comment: Try updated. But IMHO it's better to use first solution :)

Comment: You’re awesome thank you. I guess I need to start practicing my XPaths then! Haha